# HM-10 not found by android device after setting IMME to 0

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, at-command, hm-10

I am new to using the HM-10, and I am trying to make it connect to my Android device.

With `+IMME` set to 0, my phone picks up the HM-10. If I connect to it through an app that I am making, a connection is successful. After connecting once, however, the HM-10 tries to connect to my phone automatically every time my phone's bluetooth is on.

I only want to start a connection via the phone, but with `AT+IMME0`, the HM-10 connects to the phone by itself. I thought that setting `AT+IMME1` would fix this issue, but now my phone cannot find the HM-10 at all.

Am I going about this wrong? What do I need to do to get my desired outcome?

Comment: Though the solution I proposedI seemed fine to me, it seems to not work. Since I don't have an HM10 device to test and improve my answer, I have to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

AT+IMME1 put the HM10 in manual mode, meaning the bluetooth radio is not turned on until it receives AT+START, AT+DISC?, AT+DISI? or AT+DISA over serial.

[Here's the relevant section in the datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIddM.png)